# set web page login password and username as the system login password and username

Tags: php

How can I **set the username and login password of a log in web page
as the username and login password user uses to login into his/her 
computer**?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But wouldn't that be cool if you went to my web page and I grabbed the username and password to your machine?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will find that on just about any OS, it isn't possible to get the user's password.  In fact, the password itself shouldn't even be available.  Because of this, what you want to do cannot be done directly.

However, if you happen to be on an Active Directory domain with Windows clients, you can set IIS to use Active Directory authentication.  Internet Explorer users will be able to use this benefit.  IE will send a token which is then verified with the domain controller, allowing the user to log in.  You still won't get the password (again, it isn't stored), but it can allow you to authenticate for an intranet site in a few specific conditions.